# Drupal 6 Views Ticker

Tags: php, drupal

I am wondering if there is anyone out there who knows about Views in Drupal 6, specifically the Ticker aspect that could assist me with the following issue:

I have to create a news ticker that reads in the titles from a specific content type and then prints out those titles in a horizontally scrolling fashion. That is the easy part, I have gotten that to work. The part that I am having issues with is I then need to format this ticker to be a specific font, placed in a specific location on the webpage, but still take in the feed from the content types that it is supposed to. Does anyone know how to use this/ has anyone done anything that works similarly to this in the past?

I would also like to apologize if this is a dumb question, but I do really need assistance.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest enabling a views block which will allow you to move the view into any region. Defining a custom region will allow you to add the view anywhere within your site. You can also use [views_embed_views()](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_embed_view/6) which allows you to reference the view directly. Your view will likely require additional JS to load for the ticker function to work and a modified version of [using views_embed_view() with slideshow](https://drupal.org/node/823056) should help.